# If you had a T-Shirt and on that shirt were printed some part of the Ethereum codebase, what part would it be?

Tags: discussion

Shamelessly [copied from CiviCRM meta](https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/133), because I really love the idea:

> Serious question - the most popular answer will most likely make it onto one. Think hard, people, and feel free to make other thoughts and suggestions too...

If you had a T-shirt and on that shirt were printed some part of the Ethereum codebase, what part would it be?

Answer (score 2):

Creating smart contracts is what Ethereum is all about, and using 'gas' is a unique feature. This function "... returns a new contract environment for the execution of EVM". Plus it has lots of code symbols and looks cool.

```
func NewContract(caller ContractRef, object ContractRef, value, gas, price *big.Int) *Contract {
    c := &Contract{CallerAddress: caller.Address(), caller: caller, self: object, Args: nil}

    if parent, ok := caller.(*Contract); ok {
        c.jumpdests = parent.jumpdests
    } else {
        c.jumpdests = make(destinations)
    }

    c.Gas = gas //new(big.Int).Set(gas)
    c.value = new(big.Int).Set(value)
    c.Price = new(big.Int).Set(price)
    c.UsedGas = new(big.Int)

    return c
}
```

Comment: For reference https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/290e851f57f5d27a1d5f0f7ad784c836e017c337/core/vm/contract.go#L58